# ReactJS useEffect not rendering after dependency changed

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I'm currently working with React Hooks, and I'm trying to use useEffect. It supposed whenever that dependencies changed, the useEffect would re-render right? But it doesn't work for me. Here's my code :

```
const [slidesPerView, setSlidesPerView] = React.useState(0)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setSlidesPerView(() => (window.innerWidth <= 375 ? 1 : 2))
    console.log("rerender?", slidesPerView)
  }, [window.innerWidth])
```

Everytime I changed the screen size, useEffect won't re-render. I wonder what did I do wrong?

Comment: You can't just put any random variable there; it has to be something that would trigger your component to re-render -- in other words, either a state or prop variable.

Comment: so how can I track every time screen size changed?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: Hi Panji, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I'll try your answer when I get home.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`useEffect` will respond to either `props` changes or `state` changes.

Every time screen size changes component has no idea, if `window.innerWidth` is changed or not, because it is not in a `state` or `props`.

To get it working you need to store `window.innerWidth` into state, and attach a event listener to your `window`, whenever `window` size changes it will get the `window.innerWidth` and store it into the `state`, and as `state` changes your `useEffect` will get re-run, and finally your component will get re-render.

```
const [size, setSize] = React.useState(window.innerWidth)


React.useEffect(() => {
    //Attach event on window which will track window size changes and store the width in state
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateWidth);

    setSlidesPerView(() => (size <= 375 ? 1 : 2));
    console.log("rerender?", slidesPerView);

    //It is important to remove EventListener attached on window.   
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateWidth);
}, [size])

const updateWidth = () => {
    setSize(window.innerWidth)
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vfu71h)

Comment: One correction: dependencies in hooks are only valid for variables derived from props or other internal implementation details (other hooks, functions, etc). `window` is a global object though and thus isn't declared in the scope of the component.

Comment: Can you create a codepen for your issue? Did you check the Demo? You got any error?

Comment: While this is a great solution (transferring the window property to state and triggering a rerender that way), I'd recommend adding the event listener separately in a "did mount" (`useEffect` with empty dependency array). And actually return the `removeEventListener` function.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was just fooling around with a `route` prop in the `useEffect` function, passing the drilled down version of what I wanted to 'watch' i.e. `route.params.myThing`, which DIDN'T work (react didn't detect it changing). Only after I left the dependency array as the _full_ `route` prop variable , i.e. `[route]` was it detecting changes as expected. I believe this has to do with how hooks detect changes in variables, i.e. it is not a deep comparison.